# Clear a single file from p-fileupload filelist in javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, file-upload, primeng

I am working with a p-fileupload in an angular application and have added some custom templating with ng-template. I am adding what is basically a card displayed for each uploaded file and the card has a trash/remove icon on the right side where I want to allow the user to click to remove that specific file.

```
<p-fileUpload #fileUploadControl class="upload-file" name="packShipFiles" multiple="multiple" mode="advanced" [customUpload]="true" (onClear)="clearFileList()" (onSelect)="onFileChange($event)" (uploadHandler)="handleUpload($event)">
    <ng-template let-file pTemplate="file">
        <div class="file-card">
        <div>{{file.name.substr(0, 10)}} - {{file.size}}KB</div>
        <div>
            <select name="{{file.name}}" id="{{file.name}}" (change)="onTypeSelectChange($event, file)">
               <option *ngFor="let opt of fileTypeOptions" value="{{opt.code}}">{{opt.name}}</option>
            </select></div>
            <div class="file-card-remove"><span (click)="removeFile(file)" class="material-symbols-outlined trash">delete</span></div>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</p-fileUpload>
```

In my component.ts I want to handle a click of the trash icon so that it removes the file from the filelist. I have seen several examples online where they use Array.from() or something similar in order to get an array from the inputs file list and then remove the file from the array.

I do not want to do this because that has no affect on the files actually on p-fileupload. Is this possible to remove the files from that?

```
removeFile(file) {
    //how to remove?
    this.fileUploadControl.files.remove(file); //this would be great but I don't think it works that way
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by first grabbing a reference to the file upload control like this:

```
@ViewChild('fileUploadControl')
public fileUploadControl: any;
```

And then in the remove function access the control and call the remove function with the file index. For some reason I ran into build errors when I tried to declare the fileUploadControl with the type FileUpload so I had to declare it as any and then cast it when I actually wanted to call its methods.

```
removeFile(file) {
  const control: FileUpload = this.fileUploadControl as FileUpload;
  const idx = control.files.indexOf(file);
  control.remove(null, idx); //it wants the event but it can't have it
}
```